# collapsiblepanelextender is not animating in newer browsers

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an collapsiblepanelextender  that works however when being run in IE10 or chrome it does not animate in IE10 compatibility mode however it does animate

I have some javascript that is setting the speed of the animation to smooth it out a bit

```
 function LoadPanels() {
            var Test1 = $find("<%=CPEMenu.ClientID %>")
            Test1._animation._fps = 40;
            Test1._animation._duration = 0.5;
        }
```

however even if I don't use this code the collapsiblepanelextender  still does not animate.

The interesting thing to note about this is if I set the _animation._duration to 5, the extender will sit there for 5 seconds before it opens but opens in just one frame

anyone know of a way to fix this?

by the way I have 4 of these controls on the page and it is happening to all 4 of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a new class to the style sheet and assigned it to all of my panels and the problem was solved

```
.cpBody

{

height:0px;

overflow: hidden;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add 
`OnClientClick="return false;"` to the control which opens your panel. Which you have specified to   `ExpandControlID` of `CollapsiblePanelExtender`